The Twitter API found no tweet on a profile, and then return 429 error when doing the request the second time
When I use this "simple" code, first the "data" object returned by v2.userTimeline is empty (which is not true as Elon publish a lot...) and when I run the script a second time I go the 429 error, which means I did too many request, which is also not tree.
import { TwitterApi } from 'twitter-api-v2';

// Configuration des informations d'identification de votre compte Twitter

const client = new TwitterApi({
  appKey: 'X',
  appSecret: 'X',
  accessToken: 'X',
  accessSecret: 'X',
  bearerToken: 'X'
});


async function replyToLastTweet() {
  try {
    // Récupérer les informations sur l'utilisateur cible (x.com/test)
    const user = await client.v2.userByUsername('elonmusk');
    const userId = user.data.id;

    // Récupérer les tweets récents de l'utilisateur
    const tweets = await client.v2.userTimeline(userId, { max_results: 5 });

    if (tweets.data && tweets.data.length > 0) {
      // Dernier tweet
      const lastTweet = tweets.data[0];
      const lastTweetId = lastTweet.id;
      const lastTweetDate = lastTweet.created_at;

      // Afficher la date du dernier tweet
      console.log('Date du dernier tweet :', lastTweetDate);

      // Répondre au dernier tweet
      const responseText = '@test Merci pour ce tweet !';
      await client.v1.reply(responseText, lastTweetId);
      console.log('Réponse envoyée au tweet :', lastTweetId);
    } else {
      console.log('No tweets found');
    }
  } catch (error) {
// I got this exception when I run the script the second time
    if (error.code === 429) {
        const retryAfter = (error.rateLimit.reset * 1000) - Date.now();
        console.log(`Limit reached  ${retryAfter / 1000} secondes`);
    }
    
    console.error('Exception :', error);
  }
}

replyToLastTweet();

Here the exception I got when I run the script for the second time :
ApiResponseError: Request failed with code 429
    at RequestHandlerHelper.createResponseError (/home/nicolas/Desktop/projets-web/node-twitterbot/node_modules/twitter-api-v2/dist/cjs/client-mixins/request-handler.helper.js:104:16)
    at RequestHandlerHelper.onResponseEndHandler (/home/nicolas/Desktop/projets-web/node-twitterbot/node_modules/twitter-api-v2/dist/cjs/client-mixins/request-handler.helper.js:262:25)
    at Gunzip.emit (node:events:517:28)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1400:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  error: true,
  type: 'response',
  code: 429,
  headers: {
    date: 'Tue, 12 Nov 2024 16:19:14 UTC',
    perf: '7402827104',
    server: 'tsa_m',
    'set-cookie': [
      'guest_id_marketing=v1%3A173142835486274825; Max-Age=63072000; Expires=Thu, 12 Nov 2026 16:19:14 GMT; Path=/; Domain=.x.com; Secure; SameSite=None',
      'guest_id_ads=v1%3A173142835486274825; Max-Age=63072000; Expires=Thu, 12 Nov 2026 16:19:14 GMT; Path=/; Domain=.x.com; Secure; SameSite=None',
      'personalization_id="v1_NXOBPd0ytvOsaea1J5pKAA=="; Max-Age=63072000; Expires=Thu, 12 Nov 2026 16:19:14 GMT; Path=/; Domain=.x.com; Secure; SameSite=None',
      'guest_id=v1%3A173142835486274825; Max-Age=63072000; Expires=Thu, 12 Nov 2026 16:19:14 GMT; Path=/; Domain=.x.com; Secure; SameSite=None'
    ],
    'api-version': '2.114',
    'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store, max-age=0',
    'content-length': '94',
    'x-access-level': 'read-write',
    'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
    'content-encoding': 'gzip',
    'x-transaction-id': '92196b663887debb',
    'x-xss-protection': '0',
    'x-rate-limit-limit': '1',
    'x-rate-limit-reset': '1731429130',
    'content-disposition': 'attachment; filename=json.json',
    'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
    'x-rate-limit-remaining': '0',
    'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=631138519',
    'x-response-time': '102',
    'x-connection-hash': 'd3f60357701702ff4d44c3c71c7b8e581ad94ef29f042b458ae461ce11249374',
    connection: 'close'
  },
  rateLimit: { limit: 1, remaining: 0, reset: 1731429130 },
  data: {
    title: 'Too Many Requests',
    detail: 'Too Many Requests',
    type: 'about:blank',
    status: 429
  }
}

So I wait for the delay (about 10 minutes), then I got the no tweets founds message again.
As you can see, I use this lib twitter-api-v2
But when I do it directly with Axios, I got the same errors. No tweet found on the profile, or 429 error.
Did I miss something ?
Thanks
